# How to find if an item exists in an array of a document mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, find

So I have queried a specific document by email from mongoose. The document has an Array called `favoriteMovies`. I want to now query the `favoriteMovies` Array and check if an item exists in there.

```js
const user = new User({
    name: "bob",
    username: "champion",
    email: userEmail,
    favoriteMovies: [
        "Spider-Man: Far from Home",
        "logan",
        "Scarface",
        "Avengers"
    ],
    watchList: [],
    ratedMovies: []
});
```

Here is my query and it returns the entire Array, which is not the behavior I want.

```js
User.find({ email: userEmail }, { favoriteMovies: "Joker" }, function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
})
```

How would I find if an element is in the favoriteMovie array and possibly return true of the movie itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check whether document matching the query is present, then you can use `countDocument` function

```
User.countDocuments({favoriteMovies: "Joker"}, (err, count) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    console.log(count);
  }
});
```